# How to create an array or dictionary from reading excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

My code below fails and doesn't allow me to create an array including cells from g5 to g5000. How would I create a dictionary if I wanted to latter compare that column of data to another column.

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook, xlSht 
Dim filename, cellarray
filename = "c:\users\a352592\desktop\finRate.xls"

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
set xlBook = xlApp.WorkBooks.Open(filename)
set xlSht = xlApp.activesheet

cellarray = "xlsft.cells(5,7) to xlsft.cells(5000,7)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer on this site

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Why do you need a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Use .Range to store a (part of a) sheet into an array. In code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oEx : Set oEx = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oSh : Set oSh = oEx.WorkBooks.Open("E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\18376588\data\pt.xls").Sheets(2)
Dim aRr : aRr     = oSh.Range("A1:B2")
WScript.Echo TypeName(aRr)
Dim r, c
For r = LBound(aRr, 2) To UBound(aRr, 2)
    For c = LBound(aRr, 1) To UBound(aRr, 1)
        WScript.Echo r, c, aRr(r, c)
    Next
Next
oEx.Quit
```

Before asking about a dictionary, think about/publish what info you need and how you would use it to compare (what?).